# how to find an inverse function from $(0,\infty )\times (0,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

$r(u,v)=(u,2u,uv^{2})$ the Jacobian is not $3\times3$ i can find the transformation matrix but how that will help i can't find the  inverse, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Given a point $(x,y,z)=(u,2u,uv^2)$, you need to express $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$. For example we see that $u=x$, or indeed $u=y/2$ (both are fine). So can you find $v$ now?

Comment: Let me try and i will come back, thanks for the hint

Comment: in general i can  express u and v in terms of x, y and z or is there an algorith for it ?if some u,v cant be expresed cause there are not 1-1 the is not inverse right?

Answer (score 0):

$u=x$
then $z=xv^2$

$v^2=\frac{z}{x}.... v=\sqrt{\frac{z}{x}}$